# Static IP is not "Static"

Tags: static-ip

I have a client whose servers im maintaining here from Pakistan. I have two internet connection TES (fiber to home ) and Storm Fiber both have static IP addresses. But now my client is saying that the IP addresses I'm providing him are "not static". I've tested it many times by restarting my routers and same IP is assigned every time.

Is there a scenario in which static IP is not showing "static".

Is there a possibility that ISPs are assigning same IPs to multiple routers and charging them as static ip?

I've been having arguments with client for last few days and he is insisting that the IP is not static. What should i do in this condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not really make sense, bit neither does the other persons assertion. I would go back and clarify what they mean and why they say this.

There is no possibility that a static IP address does not show as static as this is a definition. (It is conceivable but exceedingly unlikely that misconfigured NAT (outside your control - at the carrier level) is changing the IP address he is seeing)

```
  Is there a possibility that ISPs are assigning same IPs to multiple routers and charging them as static ip?
```

This is technically possible but exceedingly unlikely. The ISP would need to be doing some kind of NAT, and could not legitimately call this a static IP.  You can't assign the same routable address to 2 devices  connected at the same time so you can rule this out by checking the IP of the WAN interface in your router details page (rather then going to whatismyip.com or similar)

I would communicate to the other person you are engaging outside expert help, and ask them to provide information they base their assertions on so your expert can evaluate their claim and help you resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

A IP is only static, in the regard that your ISP doesn't change it when you reconnect. There's no way for your client to know if it's going to change or not, if it hasn't already changed **unless** your actually behind a NAT that your ISP is putting up.

I don't know how you've tested if your IP is changing when you reboot your router, and this isn't a sure fire way that your IP won't ever change, it just means it hasn't changed *for now*.

So,

You can check your IP by using google (or another good IP checking site), simply by googling 'what is my ip'. Confirm it isn't changing randomly and you're not actually behind a carrier grade NAT. However, without actually paying for a static IP, you aren't guaranteed your IP won't change randomly.

Steps to fix the problem, permanently:

1. Ask your ISP how you get a genuine static IP, most ISP's will provide this on a business line, but there's normally an associated cost with it.

OR

2. Consider renting a server with a static IP, and then having all your traffic hidden behind the IP of this server.